# Laravel Echo with pusher disconnect after 30 seconds

Tags: laravel, echo, pusher

i have a game project on github:
https://github.com/ynizon/lemming

I m using pusher to send next player or message event.
When i load my browser, it works. But, if i wait 30 seconds, the echo.pusher.connection.state will be disconnected.
On the https://github.com/ynizon/lemming/blob/main/resources/js/app.js

I have added (to fix this):

```
 window.Echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind('state_change', function (states) {
                if (states.current === 'disconnected') {
                    window.Echo.connector.pusher.connect();
                }
            });
```

But, i think it s not the good method.
Do you have the same problem than me ? How correct this ?

My env file have
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Pusher dashboard Channels app settings, have you accidentally enabled `Enable authorized connections`? Enabling it will disconnect the client if it doesn't authorise into a private channel within 30 seconds.

Comment: I think no. I have only 2 Broadcast::channel function ('game-{gameId}', function ($user, $gameId) {

Comment: Can I see your front end javascript for subscribing Echo to the game-{gameId} channel?

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/ynizon/lemming/blob/main/resources/js/app.js

Comment: Disable Authorized connection. This solve my problem.